# Shape with only "inner rounded corners"

Tags: android

here is a screenshot of how my app looks like right now:

http://www.abload.de/image.php?img=unbenannt4kqjb.png

this is the code for the gray shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:top="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp" >

    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle" >

        <stroke 
            android:width="8dp" 
            android:color="#9b9c9c" /> 

        <padding 
            android:left="13dp" 
            android:top="13dp" 
            android:right="13dp" 
            android:bottom="13dp" /> 

        <corners
            android:radius="10dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" />

        <solid 
            android:color="@android:color/background_light" />

    </shape>

</item>
```

As you can see on the screenshot, the top right corner and the bottom left corner is still white. okay, i marked it with red so it's easier to recognize. i would like to color this red piece with the same gray as the gray shape, so that there is only an "inner rounded corner". i hope you understand what i mean.

i included the shape by setting it as the background of the layout.

thanks in advance.

Comment: try draw9patch image as background.

Comment: Use another simple rectangle underneath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, actually it was realy simple:

The only thing i had to do was to add another layout that encloses the old one with the background color of the shape.

That's how the layout looks like now:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#9b9c9c"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_shape"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
...
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```